# java.lang.IllegalAccessError while using Robolectric 3.6.1

Tags: java, android, junit, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

While I run JUnit tests, it throws the following error:
`java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.robolectric.annotation.Config$Builder.sdk from class org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1`

It seems that there's sth wrong here in the `RobolectricTestRunner.java(3.6.1)`

[image: screenshots]

The code in the screenshot is in the `robolectric-3.6.1-resources.jar`

Environment:

- JUnit: 4.12
- Robolectric 3.6.1
- Android Gradle Plugin: 2.3.3
- Android Studio: 3.0.1
- OS: MacOS 10.13.2

Anyone can help me? thks

Answer (score 1):

At last, I have figured out what's wrong. In the `app/build.gradle`, I had the following dependencies:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:2.6.0'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.6.1'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.2.2'
```

I had the `shadows-multidex` dependencies in version 3.2.2, which had the `org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.2.2` internal. So, after I changed the version of `shadow-multidex` to 3.6.1 as the robolectric version, everything was fine!